# calabash-ios setup clang: error: no such file or directory 'UIKit'

Tags: ios, cordova, frank, calabash

I am currently porting an existing mobile web application to IOS using PhoneGap. I wanted to test the IOS application using Frank/Calabash. I am currently facing the same issue using either of the test frameworks. For both Frank and Calabash when I try to build the app I get the following error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'UIKit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AVFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreMedia'
```

In fact these frameworks do exist in the iPhoneOS6.1 SDK.

To narrow down the problem I created a demo HelloWorld PhoneGap application and tried Frank and Calabash but got the same error.

Demo app is available at https://github.com/jmadan/phonegap-hello.git

```
XCODE version used = 4.6.3
Cordova version = 3.0.3
IOS version = 10.8.4
```

Has anyone else faced the same issue??? If Yes then any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error using calabash and frank. To fix this it was a bit hit and miss but we found that running the cordova build again to create the whole ios app fresh eg. no frank or calabash stuff in there, then putting only calabash into it worked and was able to compile and run tests.

How ever you may later run into issues with CDVViewController.h not being found or you could find that it works but if your trying to automate your tests through an ant script etc. then it will complain about not running the cucumber command in the correct place where cordova compiled your .app file so beware of this. You may need to do some clever file copying and edit your APP_BUNDLE_PATH when you get to this point.

Hope that helps...